# Finding the number of unique paths on a gird

Tags: c++, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to understand how to solve the problem of finding all unique paths in a grid using dynamic programming:

> A robot is located at the top-left corner of a m x n grid (marked ‘Start’ in the diagram below). The robot can only move either down or right at any point in time. The robot is trying to reach the bottom-right corner of the grid (marked ‘Finish’ in the diagram below). How many possible unique paths are there?

I was looking at [this article](http://articles.leetcode.com/unique-paths/) and I was wondering why in the below solution, the matrix is initialized at `M_MAX + 2` and `N_MAX + 2`, and *also* why in the function signature of `backtrack`, why the last parameter is initialized with `int mat[][N_MAX+2]`

```
const int M_MAX = 100;
const int N_MAX = 100;

int backtrack(int r, int c, int m, int n, int mat[][N_MAX+2]) {
  if (r == m && c == n)
    return 1;
  if (r > m || c > n)
    return 0;

  if (mat[r+1][c] == -1)
    mat[r+1][c] = backtrack(r+1, c, m, n, mat);
  if (mat[r][c+1] == -1)
    mat[r][c+1] = backtrack(r, c+1, m, n, mat);

  return mat[r+1][c] + mat[r][c+1];
}

int bt(int m, int n) {
  int mat[M_MAX+2][N_MAX+2];
  for (int i = 0; i < M_MAX+2; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < N_MAX+2; j++) {
      mat[i][j] = -1;
    }
  }
  return backtrack(1, 1, m, n, mat);
}
```

Then in the author's bottom-up approach solution:

```
const int M_MAX = 100;
const int N_MAX = 100;

int dp(int m, int n) {
  int mat[M_MAX+2][N_MAX+2] = {0};
  mat[m][n+1] = 1;

  for (int r = m; r >= 1; r--)
    for (int c = n; c >= 1; c--)
      mat[r][c] = mat[r+1][c] + mat[r][c+1];

  return mat[1][1];
}
```

I don't know what the purpose of the line `mat[m][n+1] = 1;` serves.

I'm not familiar with Java, so I apologize if these boil down to syntactical or language-specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, notice that the author and the second solution both use 1-based indexing. So, of course, `mat[M_MAX+1][N_MAX+1]` would be quite justified.

Now, notice the logic the author is using.

```
mat[r][c] = mat[r+1][c] + mat[r][c+1];
```

Hence, to prevent `r+1` or `c+1` from going out of bounds when `c = n+1` or `r = m+1`, instead of adding an if-statement like this:

```
if (r == m)
    mat[r][c] = mat[r][c+1];
if (c == n)
    mat[r][c] = mat[r+1][c];
```

He has decided to simply add an extra row or column with 0 value stored in it. Hence:

```
mat[M_MAX+2][N_MAX+2] = {0};
```

Finally, in a bottom up approach, one must initialize `mat[m][n]` to 1. Instead of doing that, knowing that `mat[m][n] = mat[m+1][n] + mat[m][n+1];`, he initialized :

```
mat[m][n+1] = 1; // mat[m+1][n] = 0;
```

Feel free to ask any questions in comments.